# Oracle Apex UI Translation - Point me in the right direction

Tags: oracle, globalization, oracle-apex, xliff

I have to work on building a website in Oracle Apex that should be displayed in multiple languages. Let me decompose this further.

I am assuming that there are two parts to an Apex application

1. UI & elements of the UI i.e. regions, buttons, tables, page headings
2. Data

At the moment I need to find answers on how to enable multiple language support for only the UI part of my application. Not the data.

As I can understand, there are two broad based approaches to achieve this.

1. Use the Apex inbuilt support for changing the UI elements.
2. Create a solution from scratch that is based on a database driven approach.

IS my understanding correct?

Two more questions
1. Can anyone give me a short brief on in the type of support that Oracle Apex provides for creating multiple versions of webpages / websites for my application? Alternatively just point me in the right direction by providing relevant links etc.

1. Which one of the above two approaches would you recommend? And Why?

Thanks a ton

Romi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this one I seemed to have solved on my own. The process consists of the following steps

1. Create a shadow applications for each language other than the language of the primary application.
2. Export the UI elements from the primary language application into an XML file [(XLIFF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLIFF) for the target language application (the shadow application as mentioned in 1 above).
3. Edit the XML file and enter the text descriptions for the target language application in the XML file.
4. Upload the edited XML file to the target application.

For a detailed explanation look at this [link](http://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/general/multi-language-database-applications-using-oracle-apex/) . Click [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/bookstore/apex-cookbook-chapter-256792.pdf) to create a sample multi language application in Apex.

At the time of writing this I don't see any reason for creating this feature from scratch. Why reinvent the wheel?

Any comments?

Comment: I think you're correct on most. I'd offer more but haven't dabbled with translations yet. I'd also point you in the [Oracle documentation about translating apps](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35125/global.htm#BABIIDBJ)